# Event is not getting fired

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

I am trying to use the `WebWorkerStarted` and `WebWorkerFinished` from `TWebbrowser` however the events just don't get fired at all.

How can I get these events working? I want to see which worker threads are getting launched from `TWebbrowser`.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.OleCtrls, SHDocVw;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    WebBrowser1: TWebBrowser;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure WebBrowser1WebWorkerFinsihed(ASender: TObject; dwUniqueID: Cardinal);
    procedure WebBrowser1WebWorkerStarted(ASender: TObject; dwUniqueID: Cardinal; const bstrWorkerLabel: WideString);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('www.stackoverflow.com');
end;

procedure TForm2.WebBrowser1WebWorkerFinsihed(ASender: TObject; dwUniqueID: Cardinal);
begin
  // does not fire
end;

procedure TForm2.WebBrowser1WebWorkerStarted(ASender: TObject; dwUniqueID: Cardinal; const bstrWorkerLabel: WideString);
begin
  // does not fire
end;

end.
```

Comment: Did you assign them to the component?

Comment: Are you sure the pages you navigate to actually use web workers? I am under the impression that this is something the page script explicitly uses (or not).

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, I might be wrong but I think OP does not understand what this events means, and what is a HTML WebWorker... +1 for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As documented [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser) :

> By default, TWebBrowser uses IE7 Standards mode even if the run-time environment installed the latest IE (for example, IE11).

WebWorkers were introduced in IE10 so you must have IE running in a more current mode.  At least two registry keys need to be set (more if supporting both 32/64 bit):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER) 
  {\Wow6432Node}
  \SOFTWARE
  \Microsoft 
  \Internet Explorer
  \Main
  \FeatureControl
  \FEATURE_BEHAVIORS
     {NEW DWORD ->  'YourApplication.exe'
     {    VALUE -> 1
```

Also (for example, IE11 mode)

```
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (or HKEY_CURRENT_USER) 
  {\Wow6432Node}
  \SOFTWARE
  \Microsoft 
  \Internet Explorer
  \Main
  \FeatureControl
  \FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION
     {NEW DWORD ->  'YourApplication.exe'
     {    VALUE ->  0x2AF8
```

This will cause the internet explorer instance wraped by TWebBrowser to run in IE11 mode, supporting WebWorkers, etc. You should probably do some sort of sanity check against the installed version of IE before setting this value.  More information about valid entries [can be found on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation).

This still does not raise any `WebWorker` events for me when navigating to StackOverflow (are you sure it uses them?).  As a verification test, this WebWorkers demo page does raise a `OnWebWorkerStarted` event :

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://whatwg.org/demos/workers/primes/page.html');
```